# Expressing starting position of a roller coaster on a track so that it can then go through a loop de loop by unknowns

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

I would like to have the steps to do part (a) only.

I tried using [P.E. at h1]=[(K.E.+P.E.) at h2] to find the expression but the mass m will be removed in the end, not fulfilling the requirement of expressing with m.

So how do I solve this question?

[image]

Comment: Its a misdirection in the question, to confuse you. The relation between the quantities mentioned is independent of the mass of the body.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$h_1$ depends on $h_2$, $v_2$ and $g$. The mention of $m$ in part (a) of the question is either misdirection or a misprint for $g$.